# How to kill/fix BROKER_RECEIVE_WAITFOR waiting session

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, service-broker

I have a SQL Server session which has BROKER_RECEIVE_WAITFOR. I tried to kill it but it doesn't get killed.

What is the option to Kill/Fix this session?

Also how to prevent this wait type in the future?

Comment: That indicates there is a [Service Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker) waiting for input somewhere on your server, e.g.: Database Mail. Some things you shouldn't kill.

Comment: If there is a service broker waiting for input. How do we identify it. And what is the resolution to stop/kill it.

Comment: Have a look in the Service Broker Catalog Views, as mentioned in the above link.